# Выбор инвайт-кода

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

Подскажите начинающему как с помощью PDO выбрать из базы инвайт коды, затем сравнить их с тем, что введено в POST, если будет совпадение - статус инвайта(status) меняется с 0 на 1 и автоматом в базу записывается текущая дата (date_status) использования инвайта? В таблице инвайтов есть всего 3 столбца - invite,status,date_status. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала попробуй

```
"SELECT * FROM invites where invite = $_POST['invite']"
```

Затем посмотри, как работает условие и что записывает тебе в массив -

```
if ($invite->execute(array($_POST['invite']))) {
    while ($row = $invite->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

И почитай про PDO запросы и sql выборку данных типа `INSERT` и `UPDATE` раз возник такой вопрос.